# OpenACC vs OpenMP

Tags: windows, ubuntu, gcc, openmp, openacc

Hello I test OpenACC vs OpenMP vs Nothing, but i get strange result.

- Code:

  ```
      #include <stdio.h>
          int main () {
          int a,sum=0;
     (#pragma omp for/#pragma acc parallel loop/nothing)
     for( a = 0 ; a < 2000000000; a = a + 1 ){
       sum+=a%2;
     }
   printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
     return 0;
  }
  ```

  1. I use subsystem Ubuntu for windows 10
     (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 ) and
     GCC 7.1(C compiler) and get following result: Nothing = OpenMP(correct result in about 5 sec) ; OpenACC faster, but gave wrong result(0 vs 1 000 000 000)
  2. I use VMware with Ubuntu and result is: Nothing gave
     nothing(program executing infinitely and I just close terminal); OpenACC
     showed result faster then OpenMP, but showed wrong result again.
  3. If I use Intel C++ compiler from console with OpenMP I get about 1.3sec vs ~5 sec in Ubuntu

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple different threads overwriting `sum`, and therefore you are getting wrong results. You need to tell it that this is a "reduction"

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
```

or

```
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:sum)
```

Comment: Yeah, this work and I get about 5 sec with correct result, but with Intel C++ compiler and OpenMP I get 1.5 sec, how I can go faster?

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with in optimized rather than debug mode (`-O2` or `-O3`). Make sure you've correctly specified OpenMP on the command line for GCC (`-fopenmp`).

Comment: I test VS and Intel Compiler one more time, with OpenMP I can get 1.2 sec, without parallelization I get 0,8sec,wtf.

Comment: I get 0.35s for non-parallel, 0.13s for parallel. Make sure you're measuring real time rather than CPU time (CPU time will add up the time spend thinking about each thread, so will never be "faster"). Beyond that I don't know

Comment: You talk about OpenACC or OpenMP?With #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) I can get 0.28sec.

Comment: My times are with OpenMP

Answer (score 0):

Google 'race condition'
In fact,The newer versions of PGI OpenACC  are smart enough to detect reduction on a given variable. That does not mean you should write potentially buggy code